# Asked 5 questions that got no responses: did I do something wrong?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I feel like I might not be posting in the correct format or perhaps I'm just posting about a topic most people don't have much experience with.

Either way - how can I format my questions to get better responses? I've posted 5 questions here this week (all somewhat related) and have gotten zero answers on them.

Is there anything I can do to make these posts more attractive to other StackOverflow users?

[YouTube API does not play videos as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103564/youtube-api-does-not-play-videos-as-expected-java-android)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132212/adding-thumbnails-with-youtube-api-for-android

[Video from Youtube API does not play onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203009/video-does-not-play-onclick-youtube-api-for-android)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203421/all-thumbnails-appear-the-same-youtube-api-for-android

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225336/fatal-exception-main-nullpointerexception-at-com-google-android-youtube-player

Comment: Well, the first thing that jumps out at me is the **giant** blocks of code.  You should really be trimming them down to a minimal repo; only include as much as is really needed.  Expecting people to actually sort through that much will *drastically* reduce the number of possible answerers.

Comment: Also, thanks for coming by here to ask (nicely! which you'd think would be the norm, but somehow isn't) how to improve. I hope we can help you out and you can get some answers to your questions soon.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate everyone's feedback... I'm just stuck and I REALLY need help : )

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow isn't really the place were you can just do a code dump and expect us to perform an extended troubleshooting session with you.  You need to try and point us in the right direction.  If your problem is lack of knowledge, you need to try and shore that up first.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem...  it's just my first time using the youtube API for android and I have a few questions regarding it that aren't very well documented here or elsewhere

Comment: just another note: You could answer some of your own questions yourself you already solved, pointing out what the problem was. "Adding Thumbnails..." was obviously solved by yourself because it doesn't exist in "YT API does not play as expected" anymore.

Answer (score 23):

You need to take a bit of time to slow down and work through what you're trying to ask. That's quite a number of questions over the past five days, and each of them could use a bit more work and forethought. We understand that users who are new to an API/utility/language may have a lot of questions, but we do still ask that you carefully formulate your questions. To put it shortly: Stack Overflow is a site for specific questions with specific answers, and isn't effective as a debugging service.

Another quick note: When somebody looks at your questions, you've got about fifteen seconds before they decide whether they plan to answer it. In order to make your questions look more appealing, here's specific advice for your questions:

- **Please take a bit more time to research your question.** Take a look at this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users The questions you have, as written, do not actually give the impression that you've done research. This is sort of along the lines of "What have you tried?", except it's more a matter of "What have you looked through?" Showing people you've gone through the effort of research demonstrates that you respect their time.

  Part of this is in demonstrating that you have some basic knowledge about the utility you're using. If it looks like you don't understand the fundamentals (again, regardless of whether you actually do), people will tend to avoid posting answers. So, in the case of some of these questions, the advice may simply be, work with the API for a bit and see if you find the answer.
- **Please do not include large blocks of code.** While they may be helpful, do try to limit it to what you think is absolutely needed. If others find something is missing, they will comment and ask you to include it. For instance, you could remove almost all of your imports and lose no information.

  The reason for this is twofold: First, posting large blocks of code is intimidating, and people do not wish to spend too much time reading and deciphering what it is you've done. Second, there is information in there which is not absolutely necessary to your question. This gives the impression that you encountered an error and dumped your code onto Stack Overflow without second thought, which is probably not the case.

  I will highlight [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225336/fatal-exception-main-nullpointerexception-at-com-google-android-youtube-player) in particular. You've included about three pages of code there. I'm sure you'd get a response if you edited it down to exactly the code which is likely the root of the issue. If you don't know what part of the code is at the root of the problem, then it would be wise to figure that out before asking.
- **Please take a bit of time to think about your question titles.** Specifically, two things: As you've already included [android-youtube-api](/questions/tagged/android-youtube-api), including the name of the API in the title is not actually necessary. Take a look at the questions list, and you'll see the tags right underneath the question.

  Second, please take a moment to consider how your question title reads. I pull the example:

  > FATAL EXCEPTION: main NullPointerException at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView$1.a(Unknown Source)

  This title could use a bit of work to describe the problem more clearly. Having a well-defined title will draw potential viewers to your question, which will help you in the long run.
- **When writing questions, cut directly to the point**, but include all details which are relevant to what you're saying. I'll pull this block from one of your questions:

  > I'm getting a fatal exception when attempting to set different thumbnails in my app. Does anyone know how this can be avoided? I don't know of any other way of setting the thumbnails.

  There are a couple problems with this. The first sentence is slightly unclear: you're getting a fatal exception when you set thumbnails, but thumbnails *where*? The first questions I have are "What thumbnails are these?" and "What are their sizes?" and "Where are you trying to put them?"

  At the end of this paragraph, the reader is wondering which thumbnails, how you're setting them, and what you're doing. What I'd recommend is **inverting your question**: Tell the reader what you've done and why you've done it, *then* explain why it doesn't work the way you intended. That way, the reader understands your intent and code before they see exactly what the problem is.
- **Be wary of posting questions which sound like duplicates.** People actually *do* check which questions you've asked, and are less likely to answer questions from people who have posted multiple questions about nearly the exact same topic.

---

### tl;dr

Respect the time of the people who are answering your questions. You can do this through a few ways: Enhance the readability of your questions; indicate that you've done research/understand the problem; only include the code which is necessary for understanding and solving your problem. These three things are at the root of the lack of activity on your questions.

As it stands, most of these questions read: "I am having a problem, and don't understand it. Here is my code..." While one might imagine this is a helpful question, this is an understandable mistake. The problem with questions like this is that the reader is left trying to figure out what your intent is, and what the ultimate goal for your question is.

---

This came out a lot longer than I expected it to, but then again, you asked for help :]

I don't mean to sound harsh in this answer, but some tough advice may, hopefully, be of use to you.